# How to solve the equation $Au+Bv=C$

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

How do I solve $Au+Bv=C$ Where $A$ and $B$ are constant known matrices that are nxn, $C$ is a constant known nx1 vector while $u$ and $v$ are unknown nx1 vectors with the condition given that $u_i = \frac{1}{v_i}$ for all i. Please help.

Comment: How can $C$ be a matrix that is $n \times n$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139998/solving-a-system-of-quadratic-equations

Comment: yes sorry I miss wrote, C is a vector that is nX1